# How to create a Relative File Path

Tags: c#

I have a link which im reading into stream reader - @"C:\Users\James\Desktop\tweets.txt"

I have the text file in the same folder as the source code and .exe

How would i change '@"C:\Users\James\Desktop\tweets.txt"' to a relative file path?

Comment: sorry not clear, what you're asking for ? "Generic" for what?

Comment: Did you mean a **relative** path?

Comment: Must be relative then? i was told it was generic?

Comment: I changed your question to reflect the comments

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current assembly/exe path by using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` . Once you get that you can easily append the text file name in the path to access your text file

You can also get the path of folder which contains your exe by using `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

As mentioned by Boo you can do

```
Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Text File Name");
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `Path.Combine(string,string)` should be called instead of just doing string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean relative path? You could try this:

```
Uri srFile = new Uri(@"C:\Users\James\Desktop\tweets.txt");

Uri projFile= new Uri(@"C:\MyprojectDirectory\Project\...");



Uri relativePath = projFile.MakeRelativeUri(srFile);
```

Comment: I have to hand in an assigment that readees in a file. i was told there is a way you can read it from the same folder? regardless of where it is?

Comment: You an use `Haris Hasan's` answer to get the value of `projFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Application.StartupPath property:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
string myApplicationPath = Application.StartupPath;
```